# yii2 loading jquery again with JqueryAsset

Tags: php, yii2

I have added the jquery in the header in the layout view. I have commented the code in AppAsset.php

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        /*'css/site.css',*/
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
    ];
}
```

But when I view source the page the jquery is loaded again, I have debugged the code and found out that it was loaded from vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\JqueryAsset.php

I'm not sure how to block this js from being added 
code of JqueryAsset.php

```
class JqueryAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/jquery/dist';
    public $js = [
        'jquery.js',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Normally Jquery is loaded  by the $depends content.. but is also load form plugins  ..or widget .. check in your layout and in your view if you don't register others asset that can include jquery or  widget .. fhat require this

Comment: $this->registerJsFile('@web/assets/plugins/jquery.js', ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
I have added this line in my layout files